# Merge, Combine 2 column in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 different dataframes and I was able to join them together based on g_id. Just like below:

```
df1 = dfx.join(df_gi, regexp_extract(trim(dfx.LOCATION), ".*/GDocs/([0-9]{1,5})/.*", 1) == df_gi.g_id, "inner")\
                .select (dfx["*"], df_gi["G_Number2"])
```

Now, dfx daraframe has a column called G_Number1 and df_gi dataframe has a similar column called G_Number2, Both of these columns combined solves the missing pieces ... Meaning one column has some information and the other has some. Combining both together is the output needed.

[image]

How can I achieve in pyspark?? I tried the concat function .. but i was way off.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn('Output', f.coalesce('G_Number2', 'G_Number1'))
```

Notice this will prioritize `G_Number2` column when both are not null, if you need the other way, just switch the order of the two columns.

Comment: Thanks. this is great.